# Trying to get String from App.config File

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, app-config, configuration-files

I'm desperately trying to make a working `app.config` file in which I want to save the connection strings for my database connections.

This is my `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Con" value="User Id = *******;password=**;data source=  (DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ******)(PORT = 1525))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = emtst)))"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And when I try to read it here:

```
  string connStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Con"];
  this.odacManager = new ODACManager(connStr);
```

I just get an empty string. I'm using `System.Configuration`.

I've also tried to use

```
ConfigurationManager.Connectionstring["Con"].ConnectionString
```

but that also didn't work.

Comment: FWIW, you wouldn't get it from a `ConnectionString` property as it's not defined as being a connection string - it's just an application setting.

Comment: Your code works fine here. Try to rebuild your solution and check if it helps.

Comment: Are you using this `app.config` in a class library project? That won't work, since the class library always gets its config settings from the **host application** that's running and using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `<connectionStrings>` element in your config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="Con" 
            connectionString="User Id=*******;password=**;data source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ******)(PORT = 1525))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = emtst)))"/>
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and then read it out as:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString;
```

**Update:**

In .NET, class library projects cannot have their own config files - they won't be used and won't be evaluated at runtime.

If your class library needs any configuration, you need to put that configuration into the **host application's** `app.config` (or `web.config`) so that the class library can find it there (and use it).

Comment: True, but doesn't answer the question. The problem is an entry can't be read that should be possible to read.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: but it's not using the `<connectionStrings>` section for its connection strings, which is the **generally recommended** thing to do in .NET

Comment: True, but I think we should focus *first* on the actual problem.

Comment: @marc_s when I try using your Solution I get NullRefernceExeption was unhandled by user code.

Comment: @Daniel: I asked whether this is used from a **class library** - that would explain this behavior. The null reference exception just means the `ConfigurationManager` doesn't find the file and/or the entry in the file ....

Comment: @marc_s I think I am. I'm handling the Data-Access in a seperate .DLL for my Project.

Comment: @Daniel: you need to put this configuration information into the `app.config` (or `web.config`) of the **host application** that's using your data access library ....

Comment: @marc_s Ah :) So that was the mistake. :D Thank you very much :) now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

try

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Con"].ToString();
```

Comment: The array accessor already returns a string, so this is pointless. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb(v=vs.110).aspx